# Disable Hover only for X-Axis

Tags: activex, teechart

Below is the answer for this:
TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Selected.Hover.Visible = False

But in my case there is no function in axislabel.h which provide me the selected item details.

TChart1.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetLabels().????????

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem. I think there are some headers missing to make it work in VC++.
I've added it to the public tracker to be further investigated:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1280

We expect to publish a maintenance release this September and hopefully will include this fix.

**Edit:**
Find [here](http://www.teechart.net/files/public/support/VCHover.zip) the missing headers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I've modified the zip I prepared a few days ago and edited the answer above.

Comment: Hi CAxisLabels doesn't have any exposed function which return CTeeSelected object or pointer.